# Running into issues in Android Studio while syncing Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, ide

I have scoured this forum for hours and so far nothing has been able to help me. My last question got no response. 
Basically, my friend and I are working on an android app, and he sent the source code for me to import to Android Studio, however when I do that I get the error:

> 12:08:24 PM Gradle sync started
>   12:08:26 PM Gradle sync failed: exception during working with external system: 
>              Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Any ideas?

My Log:

> 2016-03-12 12:08:26,997 [132922193]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState                      Sync with Gradle for project 'ProjectenVision' failed: exception during working with external system:
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
>   2016-03-12 12:08:27,094 [132922290]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang -               Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2016-03-12 12:08:27,094 [132922290]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2016-03-12 12:08:27,100 [132922296]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2016-03-12 12:08:27,101 [132922297]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
>   2016-03-12 12:08:27,752 [132922948]   WARN - inspections.IntellijLintClient - No projects found for [] 
>   2016-03-12 12:08:43,762 [132938958]   WARN - inspections.IntellijLintClient - No projects found for [] 
>   2016-03-12 12:12:44,034 [133179230]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
>   2016-03-12 12:12:52,591 [133187787]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
>   2016-03-12 12:33:06,723 [134401919]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
>   2016-03-12 12:33:25,843 [134421039]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl -     Updating issues cache (every 20 min)

Answer (score -1):

Are you both using the same build version of android studio?

Comment: I believe so. I don't think that should cause a problem though, I should just be able to change the gradle version and build...right?